# Copying a picture smaller in python

Tags: python, image

I am trying to write a function to receive a picture, make it smaller by a factor of two and put that picture into a blank canvas. I feel like I have it typed out right but it keeps giving me the error:

```
getPixel(picture,x,y): y (= 480) is less than 0 or bigger than the height (= 479)
```

The error was:

```
Inappropriate argument value (of correct type).
An error occurred attempting to pass an argument to a function.
```

Here is my code:

```
def makeSmaller(Picture):
    pic = Picture
    width = getWidth(pic)
    height = getHeight(pic)
    canvas = makeEmptyPicture(width /2 , height /2)
    sourceX = getWidth(canvas)
    for x in range (0, getWidth(canvas)- 1):
        sourceY = getHeight(canvas)
        for y in range (0, getHeight(canvas)- 1):
            color = getColor(getPixel(pic, sourceX, sourceY))
            setColor(getPixel(canvas, x, y), color)
            sourceY = sourceY + 2
    sourceX = sourceX + 2
    show(pic)
```

Comment: Perhaps you're not passing an object of type `picture` (whatever that is, I'm not really familiar) to your `makeSmaller` function.

Comment: and why aren't you using PIL - Python Image Library - already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need:

```
color = getColor(getPixel(pic, sourceX-1, sourceY-1))
```

So that you don't go out of bounds.  Right now whats happening is that you're trying to access a pixel that doesn't exist, because you have:

```
sourceY = getHeight(canvas)    #sourceY = 480
```

but the pixels are indexed from 0 to 479.

---

I think all you need is something like this.  You were making a lot of unnecessary stuff.

```
def makeSmaller(pic):

    #setup the canvas to draw to
    width = getWidth(pic)
    height = getHeight(pic)
    canvas = makeEmptyPicture(width /2 , height /2)

    #loop through all pixels of the canvas
    for x in range (0, getWidth(canvas)- 1):
        for y in range (0, getHeight(canvas)- 1):

            #grab the appropriate pixel from the original picture ( *2 )
            color = getColor(getPixel(pic, x * 2, y * 2))

            #assign that color the corresponding pixel on the canvas
            setColor(getPixel(canvas, x, y), color)

    show(pic)
```

Comment: I think you have more than one error with this.  Shouldn't `sourceY` be starting at 0?  You have `sourceY = height` and then you're incrementing `sourceY`, which would push it out of bounds